How easy is it to adapt a Mothership 0e adventure to Mothership 1e?
I have Mothership 1e. I am thinking of picking up an adventure, Gradient Descent, but it warns that it was published for Mothership 0e. How hard is it to adapt an adventure intended for 0e to 1e?
